# cluster filter geojson mapbox

Tags: filter, mapbox, markerclusterer

Im trying to call a my geojson files that were transform to cluster via a filter, but it doesnt work.I apply an alert to the filter "san pedro" and it works but the cluster was set to active.
in

```
var marcadores = L.mapbox.featureLayer('geojson/todos.geojson').on('ready', function(e) {
        var clusterGroup1 = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();

        e.target.eachLayer(function(layer1) {
            clusterGroup1.addLayer(layer1);
        });
     mapa.addLayer(clusterGroup1);    
    });


    $('.menu-ui a').on('click', function() {
        var filter = $(this).data('filter');
        alert(filter);
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
         marcadores.setFilter(function(f) {
         alert(filter === 'sanpedro');
            return (filter === 'all') ? true : f.properties[filter] === true;
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

The filter will not update the cluster group layer. You have to update it too.

```
var marcadores = L.mapbox.featureLayer('geojson/todos.geojson');
var clusterGroup1 = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();
mapa.addLayer(clusterGroup1);
marcadores.on('ready', function(e) {
    clusterGroup1.clearLayers();
    e.target.eachLayer(function(layer1) {
        clusterGroup1.addLayer(layer1);
    });
});


$('.menu-ui a').on('click', function() {
    var filter = $(this).data('filter');
    alert(filter);
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
     marcadores.setFilter(function(f) {
     alert(filter === 'sanpedro');
        return (filter === 'all') ? true : f.properties[filter] === true;
    });
    marcadores.fireEvent('ready');
    return false;
});
```